# How secure is a lagged fibonacci sequence for encrypting brief messages?

Tags: encryption

Say I start with a 26-letter keyword and convert the letters into 26 integers (A=0, B=1...Z=25) nr[0] to nr[25]. Then I create a stream, nr[26] onwards, with a lagged fibonacci sequence where  nr[n]= (sum of nr[n-26] to nr[n-1] )mod 26. And I use the stream to encipher a brief message (no longer than 200 letters) in such a way that the stream is hidden.  How secure is that encipherment?

example of cipher:

ciphertext letter[n] = plaintext letter[n] + key letter[n mod 26] + nr[n+26]

Answer (score 4):

Your key only seems to consist of `n`, which should be easily brute forced. So not very secure is the only answer that can be given. `n` could be very large (a 128 bit number or so), but in that case this scheme seems *very* inefficient.

Please note the remarks on this kind of generator [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagged_Fibonacci_generator#Problems_with_LFGs) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_LCGs). So even if it is secure, it may be *very* tricky to show that it is secure (for a large `n`). There are plenty of better stream ciphers to choose from.

Comment: ${\color{green}{+1}}$ for pointing at the pitfalls…